# Расширение Google Chrome. Проблема с доступом к элементам во вложенных фреймах в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, парсер, chrome-extension

подскажите как получить доступ к элементам таблицы во вложенных фреймах из расширения. Вместо значения, я получаю *null* или *undefined*. Все вложенные фреймы на странице получают контент с одного домена.

Как я могу получить доступ к элементам таблицы, которая находится внутри вложенного фрейма? Просмотрел множество вопросов схожих с моим, но так и не нашел решение своей проблемы. Возможно, я упускаю что-то в своем коде или существует более эффективный способ достижения этой цели?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Вот пример структуры страницы, которую нужно парсить:

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Outer Frame</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <frame name="mn_mgn">
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>Inner Frame 1</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <frame name="mn_mgn">
                <html>
                  <head>
                    <title>Inner Frame 2</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                    <frame name="mn_total">
                      <html>
                        <head>
                          <title>Inner Frame 3</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                          <frame name="mn_center">
                            <html>
                              <head>
                                <title>Inner Frame 4</title>
                              </head>
                              <body>
                              <frame name="other_frame">
                                    <html>
                                    <head>
                                      <title>Other frame</title>
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                    </body>
                                  </html>
                               </frame>
                              <frame name="mn_main">
                                  <html>
                                    <head>
                                      <title>Inner Frame 5</title>
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                      <form>
                                        <table>
                                          <span>Сюда надо попасть</span>
                                        </table>
                                      </form>
                                    </body>
                                  </html>
                                </frame>
                              </body>
                            </html>
                          </frame>
                        </body>
                      </html>
                    </frame>
                  </body>
                </html>
              </frame>
            </body>
          </html>
        </frame>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Так выглядит popup.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      var tab = tabs[0];
      var tabId = tab.id;
  
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        function: calculateOnPage
      });
    });
  });
  
  function calculateOnPage() {
    function calculate() {
      
      var outerFrame = document.querySelector("frame[name='mn_mgn']"); 
      outerFrame.onload = function() { 
        var innerFrame1 = outerFrame.contentDocument.body.querySelector("frame[name='mn_mgn']"); 
        innerFrame1.onload = function() { 
          var innerFrame2 = innerFrame1.contentDocument.body.querySelector("frame[name='mn_total']"); 
          innerFrame2.onload = function() { 
              var innerFrame4 = innerFrame2.contentDocument.body.querySelector("frame[name='mn_center']"); 
              innerFrame4.onload = function() { 
                var innerFrame5 = innerFrame4.contentDocument.body.querySelector("frame[name='mn_main']"); 
                innerFrame5.onload = function() { 
                  var val1 = innerFrame5.contentDocument.body.querySelector('html > body > form > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(4)'); 
                  var val2 = innerFrame5.contentDocument.body.querySelector('html > body > form > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(4)'); 
                  var val3 = innerFrame5.contentDocument.body.querySelector('html > body > form > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(4)'); 
                  
                  var result = parseFloat(val1/1000) * parseFloat(val2/1000) * parseFloat(val3/1000); 
 
                  result = result.toFixed(4); 
 
                  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "displayResult", result: result }); 
 
                  alert(result); 
                }; 
              }; 
            }; 
          }; 
        };
    }
  
    calculate();
  }
  
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === "displayResult") {
      var result = message.result;
      
      var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
      resultElement.textContent = "Результат: " + result;
    }
  });
```

Такой manifest.js

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Calculator",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Калькулятор вычисления площади",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "notifications"
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon_16.png",
        "48": "icon_48.png",
        "128": "icon_128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon_16.png",
      "48": "icon_48.png",
      "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }
```

Вот background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === "displayResult") {
      var result = message.result;
      chrome.notifications.create({
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: "icon_16.png",
        title: "Результаты подсчетов",
        message: "Результат: " + result
      });
    }
  });
```

Таким образом пытался "достучаться" до нужного фрейма из консоли, работает, но только если выбрать контекст нужного фрейма, в остальных случая возвращает null. Код:

```js
function findInFramesRec(selector, doc) {
  var hit = doc.querySelector(selector);
  if (hit) return hit;
  var frames = Array.from(window.frames);
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length && !hit; i++) {
    try {
      if (!frames[i] || !frames[i].document) continue;
      hit = findInFramesRec(selector, frames[i].document);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return hit;
}

var result = findInFramesRec("table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(4)", document);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не профии может за последнее время что-то поменялось, но:

- Проверьте, для начала можете ли вы получить доступ к другим(любым) элементам на странице? **В чем я сомневаюсь**.
- **popup.js** изначально, это скрипт, который срабатывает каждый раз, когда у вас открывается окошко(интерфейс) расширения. И он может работать, только с элементами этого интерфейса. А у вас я не вижу, чтобы он хоть куда-то подключался.
- Вот это: `"background": { "service_worker": "background.js" }` Это код для работы фоновых скриптов. Обычно подобный фоновый скрипт, кто-то использует для встраивания кода в начало/или конец страницы.
- Я не вижу у вас в манифесте(*может правила и поменялись*) правила которое указывает какой скрипт и на какой странице должен отрабатывать?
- Насколько я помню(*могу и ошибаться*), общение скрипта, что работает со страницей и интерфейса расширения происходит через сообщения или `chrome.storage`
- Когда ваш код будет работать с элементами на странице. То и доступ внутрь `iframe` вы получите после полного построения dom.
- Вам необходимо больше почитать про манифест. Скорее всего это ваше первое расширение и вы не совсем понимаете, как оно должно работать.

Comment: Я могу получить доступ к другим элементам страницы. Все верно popup.js срабатывает при открытии окна  расширения и получает документ активной вкладки, к которому я обращаюсь для поиска элементов, возможно есть какие-то способы лучше ? background.js я использую для вывода уведомления, так же он обменивается сообщениями с popup.js. На сколько знаю если в манифесте не указывать сайт выполнения скрипта, то скрипт будет выполнятся на любом сайте, тем более скрипт вызывается открытием расширения. Естественно я где то ошибаюсь и делаю что то не так, иначе бы все работало,поэтому и создал этот вопрос)

Comment: Я вас понял, значит не все так плохо.  Раньше скрипт для работы в манифесте прописывался явно в ' content_scripts ', Где собственно прописывалась и область его виденья(работы). В вашем случая я предполагаю, что у вас скрипт, что должен получать данные из фрейма получает пустой фрейм. Т.е. он срабатывает до прогрузки dom внутри фрейма. Я раньше с подобным сталкивался, но решал для себя простым способом(не уверен что вам подойдет) Перед фреймом вставлял ' button '  на страницу и биндил на нее, чтобы сначала прошелся по дому и затем искал нужные данные в фрейме.

Comment: А если сайт уже загружен и отобразился полностью для пользователя, расширение для себя все равно загружает его с нуля так сказать ? У меня есть проверка на прогруженность каждого фрейма, но видимо она не работает.

Comment: у вас 1 строка - вы дожидаетесь прогрузки dom и только потом начинает работать скрипт . Но  если dom  прогрузился, это не факт, что iframe также прогрузился. Для вас это доли секунд, но для скрипта, он мог уже пройти по dom перед тем как успел прогрузиться iframe. Возможно есть  какое-то решение для решения вашего вопроса без дополнительных извращений, как делал я, но я таких решений не находил. 
Про проверку, фрейма, скорее всего она возвращает пустоту. В подобных ситуаций, лучше побольше данных в консоль выводить. Чтобы отслеживать, что на самом деле происходит.

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать, только я ищу frame а не iframe. Спасибо :)